# passing textbox value from parent page to child window in cfm

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I am passing text field value from parent cfm page to child window which I am opening after clicking button or link.

```
<form name="parentForm" action="">
    <input type="text" id="parentValue" value="" /> 
    <input type="button" value="Open Popup"  onclick ="javascript:LaunchPopup('openP.cfm');"/> 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function LaunchPopup(page) {
         OpenWin = window.open(page, "myWindow", "width=400,height=200"); 
    }
</script>


<!--- Child page : openp.cfm --->
<script>
    if (opener.document){
        mother = opener.document;
        document.form1.popupValue.value = mother.parentForm.parentValue.value;
    }
</script>
<form id="form1">
    Value from the calling page: <input type="text" id="popupValue" value="" />
</form>
```

But for some reason, i am not able to pass the value which i entered in parent page. after i click button, i want to see the value what i entered in parent page.

Comment: When I googled the subject of your question, I found this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-Send-value-from-Parent-page-window-to-Child-popup-window-using-JavaScript.aspx

Comment: You can just pass the value along with the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Parent page**

```
<input 
    type="button" value="Open Popup"  
    onclick ="javascript:LaunchPopup('openP.cfm?parent=' + document.parentForm.parentValue.value);"
/>
```

**openp.cfm**

```
<cfparam name="url.parent" default="">
<form id="form1">
    Value from the calling page: 
    <input type="text" id="popupValue" value="<cfoutput>#url.parent#</cfoutput>" />
</form>
```

Comment: Excellent Rejith. Thanks for your help.